# Fragments inside NestedScrollView inside CoordinationLayout doesn't work properly

Tags: android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, nestedscrollview

look at [youtube screen shot](https://youtu.be/Wy19oAbvT3Q). Why when I am scrolling from bottom app bar doesn't apear?  only when I am at top and scroll down it apear?

Comment: @JavaMain post the layout code.